# Webinject - addheader change underscore into dash

Tags: web-services, web-testing

I use `addheader` in webinject test:

```
addheader="__RequestVerificationToken: {PARSEDRESULT}"
```

In request debug header (in http.log) I see:
`--RequestVerificationToken: TOKEN`

I think it should be `__RequestVerificationToken` insted of `--RequestVerificationToken`

So I can not complete the request because of wrong header.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

The "__" characters should be escaped by adding a colon `:` character.

```
addheader=":__RequestVerificationToken: {PARSEDRESULT}"
```

The problem was described here
https://github.com/sni/Webinject/issues/25#issuecomment-324053146